# Need help calculate Salt

Tags: shell-script, hashsum

Can someone please help with calculating all possible salt values from password file? so I have this password file called file_1.txt that is salted and MD5 hashed and I want to prepare a rainbow table to compare and find a match but my script is missing the salt values. Any help would be appreciated
my password file is in this format (237ac9d0,$1$237ac9d0$lcqhZ0SmxQ.0JsEDdwiEq0) and has 100 rows of salted hashes here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash
While read word

do
    hashed=`echo "$word" | openssl passwd -1 -salt ?? "$word"`
   
    while read hash
    do
            echo About to compare:
            echo word:"$word"
            echo hashed: "$hashed"
            echo hash: "$hash"
            echo --------
            if [ "$hashed" == "$hash" ]
            then
                    echo "Hash found for word "$word": "$hashed""
                    continue

                fi
        done < file_2.txt 
done < rockyoutop1000.txt
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not appropriate

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean with being "missing the salt values". The salt of a hashed password is stored with the hash itself, for reasons which should be obvious, so if you have the hashes, you have the salts. The format of those MD5-based `$1$` hashes is described in the `crypt` man page:

> If salt is a character string starting with the characters "$id$"
> followed by a string optionally terminated by "$", then the
> result has the form:
>
> ```
> $id$salt$encrypted
> ```

Comment: Thank you @ilkkachu for the reply when I said missing salt I meant what argument based on my code should I use to calculate the salt from the hash, sorry i should have made that clear.